# Find parent li id from href HTML name

Tags: jquery, html

I want to find li id of current html.

**jQuery**

```
var CurrentHTML = document.location.pathname.match(/[^\/]+$/)[0];
```

In this i will get the current html name like `Client.html or Vendor.html`.
After getting current html name, i want to get the parent li id of current html name like `li1 or li2`.

**Example**

If my CurrentHTML is Candidate.html then i want to get parent li id (li4).

**HTML**

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li id="li1"><a href="Client.html">Client</a></li>
    <li id="li2"><a href="Vendor.html">Vendor</a></li>
    <li id="li3"><a href="#">Recruitment</a>
        <ul>
            <li id="li4"><a href="Candidate.html">Candidate</a></li>
            <li id="li5"><a href="Resource.html">Resource</a></li>
            <li id="li6"><a href="ClientRequest.html">Client Request</a></li>
            <li id="li7"><a href="CandidateAssignment.html">Candidate Assignment</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="li8"><a href="Project.html">Project</a></li>
    <li id="li9"><a href="#">Security</a>
        <ul>
            <li id="li10"><a href="Roles.html">Roles</a></li>
            <li id="li11"><a href="Users.html">Users</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="li12"><a href="#">Time Sheet</a>
        <ul>
            <li id="li13"><a href="TimeTracking.html">Tracking</a></li>
            <li id="li14"><a href="TimeTrackingReport.html">Report</a></li>
            <li id="li15"><a href="TimeSheetReport.html">Download</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `$('.nav a[href="'+CurrentHTML+'"]').parent().attr('id')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
var CurrentHTML = document.location.pathname.match(/[^\/]+$/)[0],

    liId = $('ul.nav li a[href="' + CurrentHTML + '"]').closest('li').attr('id');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use attribute selector

```
$('a[href="' + CurrentHTML + '"]').parent().attr('id');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get it like this:

```
var CurrentHTML = document.location.pathname.match(/[^\/]+$/)[0];
var liId = $('[href*="'+CurrentHTML+'"]').closest('li')[0].id;
```

`$('[href*="'+CurrentHTML+'"]')` this gets your the `<a>` anchor tag which contains the `currentHTML` page then you can traverse up to its parent li with `.closest('li')[0]` then get the id with `.id`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to get element with `href` attribute and then use `.parent()`.

```
var CurrentHTML = document.location.pathname.match(/[^\/]+$/)[0],
liId = $('ul.nav li a[href="' + CurrentHTML + '"]').parent().attr('id');
```